# Allow certain characters in text field with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have done a long time research on how to allow only three certain characters to be allowed in  text field by using regex but I cannot fine a solution.

The way I try is to replace any character that it is not `+`, `(`, `)`,  (space) or a digit.

The regex I have try are the following:

```
(^[\+\(\)\s0-9]+)
```

but doesn't work. I don't know if I am wrong.

I understand the above regex as : If there string contains a character that `^` it is not `+`, `(`, `)`,  or a digit between `0-9`

and then in my Javascript I do the following :

```
var $text  =   $('#text_field');

if(0 < $text.length)
{
    $text.on(
        'keyup',
        function(e)
        {
            var $val = $(this).val();

            $val = $val.replace(/(^[\+\(\)\s0-9]+)/, '');

            $(this).val($val);
        }
    );
}
```

but unfortunately this doesn't work.

Can somebody help me please ?

I also have try the following :

```
^(^[\+\(\)\s0-9]+)$
(^[\+\(\)\s\d]+)
^(^[\+\(\)\s\d]+)$
```

but still don't work.

Comment: what test values are you using ?

Comment: Try actually typing a space " " instead of using "\s".  I've run into a few situations in Perl where that helped.

Comment: I try to create a form that the user will enter his phone number, and I like to allow them to enter only the certain characters I mentioned above. I don't mind the way the enter it. I only need to strict the character range in the specific field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud move the `^` into the character class.

That is

```
/[^\d)(+ ]/
```

- `[^\d)(+ ]` Negated character class. Matches any character other than the one in the class.

Outside the character class `^` acts as an anchor, which matches the begining of the string. Once it is moved into the character class it negates thus matching the reverse.

**Test**

```
"asdf123(+123) 1234asdf".replace(/[^\d)(+ ]/g, "");
=> 123(+123) 1234
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aG0hF3/1)

Comment: Ah !! Ok, I see. I put the `^` character outside the `[ ]` set. Thanks !! I will mark your answer as the correct one in about four minues ;) Thanks !!

Comment: @MerianosNikos Yup, It just the postition of the `^` that you got wrong. Since inside character class everything looses its special meaining, its not required to escape `(` `)` `+` etc

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you need to have the `^` inside the square brackets. Also, you should run it globally, hence `replace(/([^\+\(\)\s0-9]+)/g, "")` should work.